# Remove Symbol '[' and ']' from string variable python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to get the value of atributte from

```
airtemp = rootgrp.variables['Tair_f_inst'][0]
print(airtemp)
```

i got [[234.56]] how can i remove the '[' and ']' from that string so my value is 234.56

My Best Regrads, Thank you

Comment: Is it a string, or is it a list inside a list? Change that last line to print(type(airtemp)) and tell me what it returns.

Comment: if it is array or list then `print(airtemp[0][0])`

Comment: if i type type(airtemp) the value <class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray'>